# Encoding in MySQL with french accents

Tags: mysql, encoding

I've got a database containing a list of french word with accents.

My problem is that when I try "select length("é")" it always returns 2. So if I need to get all words with 7 letters, it will never work.

I tried the following :

```
ALTER DATABASE my_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
ALTER TABLE my_table CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
```

But it did not change anything. I also tried with latin1/latin1_bin and utf16/utf16_bin, no change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `ALTER` statements are not working is that they only set rules for how *newly* created tables will encode their text.  For your tables which already exist, the `ALTER` statements won't change anything.

I found [this great blog post](https://blogs.law.harvard.edu/djcp/2010/01/convert-mysql-database-from-latin1-to-utf8-the-right-way/) which describes how to use `iconv` to convert an existing MySQL database from `latin1` to `utf8`.  Here is the command:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table my_database | replace CHARSET=latin1
    CHARSET=utf8 | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 | mysql my_database
```

The other answers which mentioned the distinction between `LENGTH()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()` are correct and you should also pay attention to this.

Comment: NO.  Don't convert utf8 as if it were latin1.  The data in the table is probably correct; the `iconv` will mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()`. `LENGTH` returns the length in bytes which are not always 1 in utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

The LENGTH function returns the number of bytes.

You need to use the [CHAR_LENGTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function, it returns the number of characters regardless of the number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> "select length("é")" it always returns 2.

That implies that you probably already have the schema set correctly.  Do not do any ALTERs unless there are other issues.

As further confirmation, `SELECT HEX(col) ...` -- you should see `C3A9` for `é`; that is the hex for the utf8 encoding.

Comment: If you have already done the `iconv`, that letter will show up as `C383C2A9` and `LENGTH` will now be 4 -- these imply "double encoding".  To undo the iconv, `CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX(col) USING utf8) USING latin1)) USING utf8)` _might_ work.